# How to create a Javascript object that countains only round brackets (parentheses)

Tags: javascript

I printed out a Javascript variable to the console log (Firefox) and it gives this:

`POLYGON ((138.5007 -34.82787,138.51838 -34.82787,138.51838 -35.01713,138.5007 -35.01713,138.5007 -34.82787))`

If I check the type with typeof it gives object.

How can I recreate this object? Normally objects have curly braces, so how do I create this?

Comment: that could be an object with a custom `.toString` property

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: Why do you want to recreate it? What use is it?

Comment: `console.log(yourobject.toString)` (note, no `()`) you may see the code that the object uses

Comment: If I print console.log(yourobject.toString it gives this: function(){return this.Tc([this.rb.toUpperCase()," "]).join("")}                                                                         It is the return from the HERE Maps library group.getBoundingBox()